# Timer stops when new view controller loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios7, nstimer

I make one 30:00 min countdown timer, now when I load next page and back on first page my timer is on but label which show time it's stopped.

Any idea for that when I come on first page and my timer is on and start at same point, in short I need run my timer in background.

This is the code which I use in same view controller where the timer is, but it's not working.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [Timecount invalidate];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   //    [self countdownTimer];
} 

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self countdownTimer];
}

-(void)countdownTimer 
{
  secondsLeft = hours = minutes = seconds = 0; 
  if([Timecount isValid]) 
  { 

  } 
  Timecount = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show us whats in  `countdownTimer`

Comment: -(void)countdownTimer{
    
    secondsLeft = hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
    if([Timecount isValid])
    {
        
    }
    Timecount = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

Comment: Please include code in your question and not in comments , so others can also see it and is readable

Comment: Add updateCounter method in your query post.

Comment: ok, how i do timer run in background ?

Comment: Use GCD and Transfer Task to Background